# Where to see Firebase Analytics event custom parameters in console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I defined a custom event and am logging it as follows:

```
Analytics.logEvent("upload_art", parameters: ["size": ((art.size ?? 0) / 1000000)])
```

I am seeing the event propogate into the console after 24 hours, but I don't see any reporting on the custom parameter `size`. I'd like to be able to see reporting on this and an average. How do I set this up? In older blog posts from the firebase team, it seems as though I should be able to see this in the console but my console looks like this:

[image]

(I am seeing that "size" is being correctly logged in the debug view.)